# Internal table isn't modified from table control

Tags: abap, dynpro

I have an table control (`ctrl`) and an internal table (`snctab`).
I want to add items `snctab` from the table control. I can add but not modify a record from `snctab`. Here are my PBO and PAI modules:

```
PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT.
    MODULE status_0100.

    LOOP AT snctab WITH CONTROL ctrl CURSOR ctrl-current_line.
    ENDLOOP.

PROCESS AFTER INPUT.

    LOOP AT snctab.
        MODULE update.
    ENDLOOP.

    MODULE user_command_0100.

    MODULE update INPUT.    "my update module
        READ TABLE snctab INDEX ctrl-current_line.
        IF sy-subrc <> 0.
            APPEND snctab.
        ELSE.
            MODIFY snctab INDEX ctrl-current_line.
        ENDIF.
    ENDMODULE.                 " UPDATE  INPUT
```

Comment: Just to clarify, when an item is in both `scntab` and `ctrl`, the contents of `ctrl` is not being updated in your code? But if the record doesn't exist in `ctrl`, it will successfully be added to `ctrl`?

Comment: Actual problem is when an item is in both scntab and ctrl, i am changing some fields of this record on the screen but there is no change neither of snctab and ctrl on background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the update module like this and problem solved.

```
 MODULE update INPUT.    "my update module
    MODIFY snctab INDEX ctrl-current_line.
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
       APPEND snctab.
    ENDIF.
 ENDMODULE.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `LOOP` statement in the PAI module does not take the table control into account - you are using an obsolete variant that was used to process step loops there. Check the demo program `DEMO_DYNPRO_TABCONT_LOOP` in your system to see a working example.